# Terminal MAC OSX uptime command showing 2 users

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

Hi I am pretty new to programming.

I have started using terminal on my mac.

I tried using the uptime command on localhost and it says there are two users. However I'm the only one logged onto my laptop.

Why does it say 2 users?

Comment: I can't see how this is related to programming. Maybe belongs on [su]?

Comment: Type `w` at the command line to see those users. They will both be you; one on `console` and the other on `s000`.

Answer (score 7):

You are the only physical user logged in but there may be other processes using the TTY. Try running the command 'w' and you will see all the users using the terminal. If you open five terminals, you will see 5 users logged in. By default when you open 1 terminal session, you will have 1 user for terminal use and 1 for console use. You will always have minimum of 2.